# How pass a large array from js to c++ using emscripten?

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays, emscripten

I want to pass a large array from js to c++ using emscripten. But am only able to pass a small array of sizes 3 or 4. I keep getting this error for large arrays `Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds`
How would I pass an array of length 160000?

.js

- Import function from Emscripten generated file.
- Create example data to test float_multiply_array.
- Get data byte size, allocate memory on Emscripten heap, and get
  pointer.
- Copy data to Emscripten heap (directly accessed from Module.HEAPU8)
- Call function and get result.
- Free memory.

```
function __CPPModule__(size,iterations) {
  const myModule = Module();
  return myModule.then((Module) => {
    // Import function from Emscripten generated file
    var cppf= Module.cwrap('testFunction', 'number', ['number', 'number', 'number']);

    // Create example data to test float_multiply_array
    var data = new Float32Array(size*size);

    // Get data byte size, allocate memory on Emscripten heap, and get pointer
    var nDataBytes = data.length * data.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
    var dataPtr = Module._malloc(nDataBytes);

    // Copy data to Emscripten heap (directly accessed from Module.HEAPU8)
    var dataHeap = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, dataPtr, nDataBytes);
    dataHeap.set(new Uint8Array(data.buffer));

    // Call function and get result
    cppf(dataHeap.byteOffset, size, iterations);
    var result = new Float32Array(dataHeap.buffer, dataHeap.byteOffset, data.length, iterations);
    // Free memory
    Module._free(dataHeap.byteOffset);
    return result
  })
}
async function jsTocpp(size,iterations){
  let f = await __CPPModule__(size,iterations)
  return f
}

var size = 400
var iterations = 0
console.log(jsTocpp(size,iterations));
```

.cpp

- loop the array from world.map and add it to arr

```
class World{
public:
  //Constructor
  World(int size) {
   ...
  }

   double map[400][400] ={0.0};

};


extern "C" {
    EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE int testFunction(float *arr, int size, int iter) {
        World world(size);

        int row = size;
        int col = size;

        for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
              arr[i * col + j] = (float)world.map[i][j]; //copy the data from 2D array to 1D array
      return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the fourth argument of `Float32Array`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways for [Connecting C++ and JavaScript](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/index.html). The usual way is to use [Embind](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html). Use the [`emscripten::val`](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/val.h.html#val-as-handle) object to access the JavaScript object in the C++ code. Emscripten also offers the possibility to [Access memory from JavaScript](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-access-memory) in C++ and to create a memory view.

A simple C++ function that can be called from JavaScript to get and decode a `Float32Array` looks like this (file *testArray.cpp*):

```cpp
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
#include <emscripten/val.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void passArray(const emscripten::val &floatArrayObject) {
    unsigned int length = floatArrayObject["length"].as<unsigned int>();
    std::vector<float> floatArray;
    floatArray.resize(length);
    auto memory = emscripten::val::module_property("HEAPU8")["buffer"];
    auto memoryView = floatArrayObject["constructor"].new_(memory, reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(floatArray.data()), length);
    memoryView.call<void>("set", floatArrayObject);

    for (auto &floatValue : floatArray) {
        std::cout << floatValue << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_module) {
   emscripten::function("passArray", &passArray);
}
```

Compile the file with the `-lembind` option. e.g.:

```
emcc --no-entry --bind -O0 "testArray.cpp" -o "testArray.js" -s WASM=1
```

A simple HTML code that executes the function might look as follows

```html
<script>
    var Module = {
        onRuntimeInitialized: function() {
            const floatArray = new Float32Array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5]);
            Module.passArray(floatArray);
        }
    };
</script>
<script src="testArray.js"></script>
```

and generates to following output:

```
1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5,
```